# Changes without revisions in Gerrit

Tags: gerrit

What happened to a change, if it has no revisions?

You can find an instance of this phenomenon with [change 8906 in the LibreOffice Gerrit](https://gerrit.libreoffice.org/#/q/change:8906) or [change 9860 in the OpenStack Gerrit](https://review.openstack.org/#/q/change:9860). There is no correlation to their status or user access control.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the 8906 is a Draft change. Only the owner and the reviewers can see a Draft change.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I found it when I looked after closed changes. So probably not.

Comment: The 8906 is closed but its status is "Abandoned" (search for "change:8906" and you'll see). Probably it's a Draft change which was abandoned.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found another change, which is merged, which has also no revisions, but is neither a draft nor abandoned.